# type 'ASN1Object' is not a subtype of type 'ASN1Sequence' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart

Do you know the solution for this error?

```
parsePublicKeyFromPem(String pemString) {
  List<int> publicKey = decodePEM(pemString);
  var asn1Parser = new ASN1Parser(publicKey);
  var topLevelSeq = asn1Parser.nextObject() as ASN1Sequence;
...
}
```

- Error

```
type 'ASN1Object' is not a subtype of type 'ASN1Sequence' in type cast
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should remove the keyword 'RSA' in your header.
I have done successfully with doing the following:
change your  from
'-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY----'
to
'-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).